# Is this proof of propositional logic valid

Tags: logic

This is exercise 6, part b of Practice exercises of chapter 6 of PD Magnus forallx Introduction to formal logic

I am not sure if I used correctly the disjunction elimination rule in line number 7 since It disjuncts between two negations.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the rules of inference Magnus seems to allow, I think you're correct to have doubts about the way you've used disjunction elimination.  The form of this rule Magnus gives on p.106 is that you can infer $\ \cal{A}\ $ from $\ \cal{A}\vee\cal{B}\ $ and $\ \neg\cal{B}\ $, or $\ \cal{B}\ $ from $\ \cal{A}\vee\cal{B}\ $ and $\ \neg\cal{A}\ $. He does not appear to have a rule which allows you to infer $\ \cal{A}\ $ from $\ \cal{A}\vee\neg\cal{B}\ $ and $\ \cal{B}\ $, at least not directly.

You can, however get around this with just one extra step by using the derived rule DN (double negation) which Magnus introduces on p.114.  This allows you to infer $\ \neg\neg D\ $ from $\ D\ $, and once you have $\ \neg\neg D\ $ you can infer $\ \neg X\ $ from $\ \neg X\vee\neg D\ $ and $\ \neg\neg D\ $ using one of the forms of disjunction elimination which Magnus certainly does allow.

Comment: So to clarify, I should insert a line between my actual line 5 and line 6. And in that line, use the DN rule to transform D into ¬¬D?

Anyway, thank you for your detailed answer with the pages and all!

Comment: Yes, precisely. The argument will become
\begin{array}{l|l|lll}
5& &D& & \vee\text{ E }3,4\\
6& &\neg\neg D& & \text{DN }5\\
7& &\neg X\vee\neg D& & \text{DeM }2\\
8& &\neg X&& \vee\text{ E }6,7
\end{array}
and then proceed exactly as you have it now (except with the line numbers incremented by one).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You did use disjunctive syllogism (elimination) correctly. If you have a sentence of the form,

$$\neg x \lor \neg D$$

you would need either $x$ or $D$ to be true in order to eliminate one of the disjuncts. For example,

$$\neg x \lor \neg D$$
$$x$$
$$\therefore \neg D$$

It seems like you did this properly, so line 7 is valid.

Comment: I got D in line 5 via the disjunction elimination rule from lines 3 and 4. Then I used that D to get "¬x" in line 7 is that correct? thanks in advance

Comment: Ah! I misread your answer. Yes, you are correct. I didn't see that you had derived D earlier.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!